# Isolating misbehaving HBase coprocessor code

Tags: hbase

I am currently exploring HBase coprocessors to implement some algorithm processing on server side on row updates to a specific table on our HBase cluster. Our cluster is shared between several production applications.

Since my coporcessors are loaded and executed within the address space of RegionServer, could any misbehaving coprocessor code crash the region server? We don't want to restart/rebuild our cluster just to support using coprocessor on this 1 table.

Have any of you had any such experience? If so would be great to hear about any problems/solutions that you may have faced/implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since my coporcessors are loaded and executed within the address space
>   of RegionServer, could any misbehaving coprocessor code crash the
>   region server?

Yes, any mis-behaving coprocessor implementation will impact the service hosting it (RS or Master).

As of today there is still no isolation support, but https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4047 tracks such a feature.